# How do you index any location of a program whose size is bigger than the virtual memory?

Tags: operating-system, paging, virtual-memory, demand-paging

Virtual memory is something that can be indexed by CPU alone, a 32 bit architecture is capable of generating 2^32 locations(say byte addressable machine then 2^32 bytes=4GB).
Surely we can use demand paging if process size is bigger than RAM, but what if the process size is bigger than virtual memory itself ?
Surely, you can again use demand paging, but my question is, how can CPU locate any bytes greater than 2^32 ?  Say program is written has size of 5GB, how does cpu index the bytes greater than 5GB ? It can only generate locations till 4GB.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373944/how-does-pae-physical-address-extension-enable-an-address-space-larger-than-4g

Comment: @Sagar Can you elaborate it please, its still unclear to me